# Expiring api request caches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I've implemented API caching based on http://robots.thoughtbot.com/caching-api-requests. I'm using memory as the storage. How can I reset the cache manually without restarting the server?

I've tried using `Rails.cache.clear`, but it doesn't seem to work. The data is still getting pulled from the cache. I checked it by observing the server log for my `puts` message (as shown below).

Caching code:

```
module Meh
  class Api
    include HTTParty

    #...

    cache_name = options[:path] + "/" + options[:params].values.join(",")

    response = nil
    APICache.get(cache_name, cache: 3600) do
      response = self.class.get options[:path], query: options[:params]

      # For future debugging
      puts "[API] Request: #{response.request.last_uri.to_s}"

      # Just return nil if there's an error with the request, for now
      if response.code == 200
        response.reverse!
      else
        response = nil
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried 'rake tmp:cache:clear' or deleting the contents of tmp/cache/ manually?

Are you trying to delete the contents of the cache from within the code?

Reading through the api_cache gem, it looks like this is a memory cache, not a file cache. Which would be consistent with your reports. It also looks like there is a .delete method on the APICache api. link So APICache.delete(cache_name) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: `rake tmp:cache:clear` didn't work and there's no file in my `tmp/cache` directory. Actually, I want to create a rake task (if it's not a task yet) to clear the cache and possibly call it from my code.

Comment: Reading through the api_cache gem, it looks like this is a memory cache, not a file cache. Which would be consistent with your reports. It also looks like there is a .delete method on the APICache api. [link](https://github.com/mloughran/api_cache/tree/master/lib/api_cache) So APICache.delete(cache_name) may be what you are looking for.

Comment: I think I've solved it based on your comment. Since the latest code changes (related to deleting the key) has not been released, I had to set the source for the gem from Github. I've also noticed that deleting key from the console won't clear up the key in the running server since they're using different memory. I had to use other type of storage such as Redis to ensure deleted keys from the console will also delete the key for the running server. Maybe you can reflect your answer based on your comment. Thanks a lot for the hint.